# Laravel 5.7: Detecting duplicates in a collection based on multiple keys (done) but how to move dupes to another collection?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, collections

I have a huge collection of data (array items). Each item within should be distinguished as dupe if all values for given keys are the same. **Imagine this as a unique composite key**.

```
$recordsAll = [
    ['unique1' => 'foo', 'unique2' => 'bar', 'whatever1' => 'whatever1'], // 1st OK
    ['unique1' => 'baz', 'unique2' => 'zaz', 'whatever2' => 'whatever2'], // 2nd OK
    ['unique1' => 'foo', 'unique2' => 'kkk', 'whatever3' => 'whatever3'], // 3rd OK (because unique2 is kkk not bar)
    ['unique1' => 'bar', 'unique2' => 'zaz', 'whatever4' => 'whatever4'], // 4th DUPE (dupe of the 2nd because on both unique1 is bar and unique2 is zaz)
];
```

In the example above the unique composite key is a combination of `unique` and `unique2`.

I'm able to remove the dupes. I do it like that:

```
$recordsAll = collect($recordsAll);
$recordsCleaned = $recordsAll->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['unique1'].$item['unique2'];
});
```

I'm able to confirm that it works by counting results in both. Collection with everything should give me obviously `4`, while the cleaned one should give me `3`, and they do…

```
dd($recordsAll->count(), $recordsCleaned->count()); // prints 4 and 3
```

What I don't know how to do (or at least I have an idea but it does not work) is to store the duped record(s) in another array (collection). So I don't want to only remove the dupes and use cleaned collection. Later I also want to perform some logic on the collection containing dupes.

I thought that a simple `diff` will do the job for me, [since the documentation is quite clear](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-diff).

> The diff method compares the collection against another collection or
>   a plain PHP array based on its values. This method will return the
>   values in the original collection that are not present in the given
>   collection:

```
$dupes = $recordsAll->diff($recordsCleaned);
$dupes->all();
```

However this does not work. I tried as well with `diffAssoc` and `diffKeys`. Please help me, how I can have the 4th (duped) item and all next dupes in a brand new collection?

**edit:**

I came up with below solution, but I don't think it's good from the performance perspective as the production collection is going to have almost millions of items.

```
$recordsDupes = collect([]);
$recordsAll->each(function ($item) use ($recordsCleaned, $recordsDupes) {
    if ($recordsCleaned->contains($item) === false) {
        $recordsDupes->push($item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `diff` method on collection, then you must have collection inside collection in multi dimensional case. So, your code should be like this:

```
$recordsAll = [
            ['unique1' => 'foo', 'unique2' => 'bar', 'whatever1' => 'whatever1'], // 1st OK
            ['unique1' => 'baz', 'unique2' => 'zaz', 'whatever2' => 'whatever2'], // 2nd OK
            ['unique1' => 'foo', 'unique2' => 'kkk', 'whatever3' => 'whatever3'], // 3rd OK (because unique2 is kkk not bar)
            ['unique1' => 'baz', 'unique2' => 'zaz', 'whatever4' => 'whatever4'], // 4th DUPE (dupe of the 2nd because on both unique1 is bar and unique2 is zaz)
        ];
$recordsAll = collect($recordsAll);

$recordsCleaned = $recordsAll->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['unique1'].$item['unique2'];
});


$recordsAll = collect($recordsAll->toArray())->map(function($row) {
                                            return collect($row);
                                    });
$recordsCleaned = collect($recordsCleaned->toArray())->map(function($row) {
                                        return collect($row);
                                    });

$diff = $recordsAll->diff($recordsCleaned);
```

In above code variable `$diff` will be a collection as difference between cleaned and all. I've operated all variables in collection and you can convert them as arrays if you need.

I think you will understand above code if any problem feel free to ask.

Comment: Wow, you diff is exactly the same as mine, which means that the issue was that I didn't wrap each item within the collection `$recordsAll` and `$recordsCleaned` as collection. Well now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Glad to see it works for you. If it really helped you to solve problem then please close the question by accepting this answer.

Comment: Will do mate, will do! 

Comment: @Matt Cheers ;)